# Hibernate obtains multiple JDBC Connections from the pool during a JTA transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, ehcache

I´ve working on migrating a project from BC4J to JPA + Hibernate.
Just to start, we have migrated one entity with limited scope, and a non-expected behavior has occured.

As querying the entity with a native query, hibernate first checks ehcache to see if the query is there, as it's not, it executes a query.

```
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,465 AbstractEntityManagerImpl: Looking for a JTA transaction to join
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,465 AbstractEntityManagerImpl: No JTA transaction found
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,466 StandardQueryCache: checking cached query results in region: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,466 EhcacheGeneralDataRegion: key: sql: select linearepro0_.C_ID as C1_215_, linearepro0_.C_ID_ACCION as C2_215_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_OBS as C3_215_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_REPROCESO as C4_215_ from PISOPLTA.LNA_LINEA_REPROCESO linearepro0_ where (linearepro0_.C_LINEA_OBS=? ); parameters: DEC3_CHU, ; named parameters: {}
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,466 Cache: Cache: org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache store hit for sql: select linearepro0_.C_ID as C1_215_, linearepro0_.C_ID_ACCION as C2_215_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_OBS as C3_215_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_REPROCESO as C4_215_ from PISOPLTA.LNA_LINEA_REPROCESO linearepro0_ where (linearepro0_.C_LINEA_OBS=? ); parameters: DEC3_CHU, ; named parameters: {}
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,466 StandardQueryCache: Checking query spaces for up-to-dateness: [PISOPLTA.LNA_LINEA_REPROCESO]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,467 EhcacheGeneralDataRegion: key: PISOPLTA.LNA_LINEA_REPROCESO
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,467 Cache: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache cache - Miss
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,467 EhcacheGeneralDataRegion: Element for key PISOPLTA.LNA_LINEA_REPROCESO is null
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,467 StandardQueryCache: returning cached query results
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,467 Loader: loading entity: [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#1906]
```

After that, it seems like hiberate is going to the db for each entity returned by the query to populate it.

```
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,467 Loader: loading entity: [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#1906]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,468 AbstractBatcher: about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,468 ConnectionManager: opening JDBC connection
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,468 SQL: select linearepro0_.C_ID as C1_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_ID_ACCION as C2_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_OBS as C3_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_REPROCESO as C4_215_0_ from PISOPLTA.LNA_LINEA_REPROCESO linearepro0_ where linearepro0_.C_ID=?
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,471 AbstractBatcher: about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,471 Loader: result row: EntityKey[com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#1906]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,471 AbstractBatcher: about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,471 AbstractBatcher: about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,471 ConnectionManager: aggressively releasing JDBC connection
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,472 ConnectionManager: releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,472 TwoPhaseLoad: resolving associations for [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#1906]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,472 TwoPhaseLoad: adding entity to second-level cache: [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#1906]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,473 TwoPhaseLoad: done materializing entity [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#1906]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,473 StatefulPersistenceContext: initializing non-lazy collections
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,473 Loader: done entity load
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,474 Loader: loading entity: [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#2659]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,474 AbstractBatcher: about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,474 ConnectionManager: opening JDBC connection
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,474 SQL: select linearepro0_.C_ID as C1_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_ID_ACCION as C2_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_OBS as C3_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_REPROCESO as C4_215_0_ from PISOPLTA.LNA_LINEA_REPROCESO linearepro0_ where linearepro0_.C_ID=?
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 AbstractBatcher: about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 Loader: result row: EntityKey[com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#2659]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 AbstractBatcher: about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 AbstractBatcher: about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 ConnectionManager: aggressively releasing JDBC connection
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 ConnectionManager: releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,478 TwoPhaseLoad: resolving associations for [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#2659]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,478 TwoPhaseLoad: adding entity to second-level cache: [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#2659]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,479 TwoPhaseLoad: done materializing entity [com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#2659]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,479 StatefulPersistenceContext: initializing non-lazy collections
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,479 Loader: done entity load
```

And the worst is that it seems that each time it´s opening and releasing a JDBC connection. The following log is being repetear SEVERAL times.

```
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,474 ConnectionManager: opening JDBC connection
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,474 SQL: select linearepro0_.C_ID as C1_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_ID_ACCION as C2_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_OBS as C3_215_0_, linearepro0_.C_LINEA_REPROCESO as C4_215_0_ from PISOPLTA.LNA_LINEA_REPROCESO linearepro0_ where linearepro0_.C_ID=?
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 AbstractBatcher: about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 Loader: result row: EntityKey[com.business.entity.jpa.LineaReproceso#2659]
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 AbstractBatcher: about to close ResultSet (open ResultSets: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 AbstractBatcher: about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 ConnectionManager: aggressively releasing JDBC connection
DEBUG 2015-01-28 13:23:19,477 ConnectionManager: releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
```

Any idea of what may be causing this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your hibernate/JPA configuration ... where is your connection pooling configuration ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the JTA specification does not impose to release connections after each statement, Hibernate does that because of [some strange behavior in old application servers](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1287) which led to introducing the [`AFTER_STATEMENT` connection release mode](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-database-connection) which behaves as follows:

> The connection is released after each statement execution and
> reacquired prior to running the next statement. Although not required
> by either JDBC or JTA specifications, this strategy is meant to
> prevent application servers from mistakenly detecting a connection
> leak between successive EJB (Enterprise Java Beans) calls

So, it happens because you use a JTA environment, as opposed to a `RESOURCE_LOCAL` one.

You can overwrite this behavior by setting the following Hibernate property:

```
hibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction
```

You should be aware that there's a performance penalty associated with releasing connections after each statement, as that's after the [`after_statement`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-aggressive-connection-release/) connection release mode does.